# Why is my offcanvas-wrapper reappearing briefly after click-tap? (mobile menu)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, menu

I have a mobile menu on a one page that did not close after a tap on a menu item (menus are all redirecting to sections of the one page with anchor tags). I managed to do it by adding a footer script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#offcanvas-wrapper li a').click(function(){
    $('#offcanvas-wrapper').toggleClass('hide');
});
});
</script>
```

However, now if I want to open the mobile menu again, the menu reappears briefly after a tap/click, and then I have to click on the menu icon again to make the menu visible.
This only happens on mobile (reduce your window size to reproduce the glitch).

Here is the link of the one pager:
[the one pager](http://shinylab.com/clstp/)

Here is a 30 seconds video of the issue:
[video of the issue](https://youtu.be/INqXCKWw7yU)

Why is the menu reappearing? How can I resolve this? I can handle CSS, Html and a bit of javascript.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to just comment but I don't have enough reputiton yet to do so.

It seems like you have an "open" class that stays on the menu element when you click on a menu option. The open class disappears however when you click outside of the menu. So that could be the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Josie you pointed out something I did not think about. I'll use your insight to try to resolve this. I'll let you know :)

Comment: All right, I managed to get rid of the "open" class that was causing the brief reopening by modifying the jquery script with this `$('#offcanvas-wrapper').addClass('hide').removeClass('open');`  But now… my mobile menu won't reopen at all (it works good on desktop though) -_-' Now I can say I understand better adding, toggling, removing classes with jquery though :D